# Keychain Working but Still must enter passphrase on first decrypt

Tags: ssh, keychain, gnupg

I am using keychain to store ssh and gpg keys.  When I login and start up a terminal, I get prompted for both the ssh and gpg passphrases, then keychain reports that it has found the existing agents and keys:

- keychain 2.7.1 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
- No other ssh-agent(s) than keychain's 2740 found running
- No other gpg-agent(s) than keychain's 3301 found running
- Found existing ssh-agent: 2740
- Found existing gpg-agent: 3301
- Known ssh key: /home/ded/.ssh/id_rsa
- Known gpg key: C0A9F2F0

But if I try to decrypt a gpg file, say

```
$ gpg -d ~/.authinfo.gpg
```

I am prompted again for the gpg passphrase, but only the first time.  Decrypting again, even from a new terminal works fine.  This means that emacs gnus, for example, fails to connect unless I first do an manual decrypt.  Very annoying.

I would like to enter the passphrases once when I login.

Here is what I have in my zshrc (also bashrc) to start-up keychain:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
    eval `keychain --eval id_rsa C0A9F2F0 --inherit any-once --stop others  --nogui`
    GPG_TTY=$(tty)
    export GPG_TTY
else
    # In a non-interactive script, eval keychain, but don't try to
    # prompt for passphrase
    eval `keychain --eval id_rsa C0A9F2F0 7BBA874D --inherit any-once --stop others --quiet --noask`
fi
```

Here is my ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
# Time to live for gpg keys set
# 864000 is 10 days; max set to 100 days
max-cache-ttl 8640000
default-cache-ttl 864000
max-cache-ttl-ssh 8640000
# Use gpg-agent to serve SSH keys as well
# enable-ssh-support
# default-cache-ttl-ssh 864000
log-file /home/ded/gpg-agent.log
debug 4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be this [bug](http://bugs.funtoo.org/browse/FL-69).

Comment: Adrelanos, thanks for the pointer.  I had not seen that bug report.  At least I know it's not "just me."